# SwiftUI Sheet presented with .sheet(item: is dismissed when parent view state changes

Tags: swiftui

If a sheet is presented with `.sheet(item:` then changing the state of the sheet's parent view causes the sheet to be dismissed and then be re-presented. However if a sheet is presented with `.sheet(isPresented:` then changing the state of the sheet's parent view does not causes the sheet to be dismissed. How can I get `.sheet(item:` to behave like `.sheet(isPresented:`? I often need to use `.sheet(item:` to pass a parameter to the sheet
(as described here https://www.swiftjectivec.com/swiftui-sheet-present-item-vs-toggle/). Thank you!

```
import SwiftUI

struct SheetContentView: View {
    @State var isPresented = false
    @Binding var things : [String]
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                Button("Dismiss outer sheet", action: { dismiss() })
                Button("Add a thing", action: { things.append("\(things.count)"); })
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ThingListContentView: View {
    @State private var activeSheet: ActiveSheet?
    @State private var things : [String] = []
    
    struct ActiveSheet: Identifiable {
        var id: String {
            UUID().uuidString
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Group {
                List{
                    ForEach(things, id:\.self) { thing in
                        Text(thing)
                    }
                }
                Button("Present sheet", action: { activeSheet = ActiveSheet() })
            }
            .navigationTitle("Thing List 1")
            .sheet(item: $activeSheet, onDismiss: {
                print("ondismiss things 1")
            }) { sheet in
                SheetContentView(things:$things)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ThingList2ContentView: View {
    @State private var isPresented: Bool = false
    @State private var things : [String] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Group {
                List{
                    ForEach(things, id:\.self) { thing in
                        Text(thing)
                    }
                }
                Button("Present sheet", action: { isPresented = true })
            }
            .navigationTitle("Thing List 2")
            .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented, onDismiss: {
                print("ondismiss things 2")
            }) {
                SheetContentView(things:$things)
            }
        }
    }
}

@main
struct TestSheetApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            TabView {
                ThingListContentView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Text("Things 1")
                    }
                ThingList2ContentView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Text("Things 2")
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using

```
    struct ActiveSheet: Identifiable {
        var id: String {
            UUID().uuidString
        }
    }
```

where the `id` is a computed rather than static value.  This means that every time it is assessed it is different, therefore there is no preserved identity, and hence the view is refreshed.

Change this to:

```
    struct ActiveSheet: Identifiable {
        let  id = UUID().uuidString
    }
```

so the identify is preserved and you'll get the expected behaviour.

[I'd also comment that the overall concept of using a struct with just an 'id' in like this is peculiar, but that might just be the effect of producing a simplified minimum reproducible example]